# Arduino Uno, BLE Bluetooth Shield and Braccio Arm Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I'm running the Uno board and want to connect the BLE Bluetooth shield (http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/) to control the Braccio Arm I have.

When I sit the Braccio Arm Shield on the Uno everything works - I can control the Arm.

When I sit the Bluetooth Shield on the Uno, everything works I can find the device and connect to it using the IOS App.

When I sit all 3 together, I can still control the arm but can no longer find the Bluetooth device.

Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that the BLE Shield is using  a SPI interface therefore on Arduino Uno the SPI bus uses pins 10 (SS), 11 (MOSI), 12 (MISO), and 13 (SCK) and the Nordic’s ACI requires two hand-shake signals, RDYN and REQN, two additional pins will be used (pins 8 & 9 in the default settings), from [BLEshield](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/)
Therefore the BLE shield uses 6 pins e the [Braccio](http://www.arduino.org/products/tinkerkit/arduino-tinkerkit-braccio) uses almost all Arduino Uno pins. 
Conclusion, you probably can't have both shields together as the Arduino Uno hasn't enough pins.

You can try an Arduino MEGA and adapt the shields connections wiring them together using different pins for the Braccio interface for example

Comment: This really helped, I managed to get a Bluetooth module and find the pins that were not in use.